# Angular , mat-table, html element toggle

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, mat-table, angular12, ng-switch

How do I toggle between two html elements based on what value I have in Table column ?
As Column value is loaded into dataSource variable and I am rendering it. So is there any way I can use column value to render a specific html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish that something would react on template based on what values are in the template table, that's doable. For example, I am going to access `element.weight` and when element value is `> 10` I will render some HTML changes. In this case adding a green circle if its over 10 and a red one when `< 10`.

```html
  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}}
    <div *ngIf="element.weight >= 10" style="height: 10px; width: 10px; border-radius: 10px; background: green"></div>
    <div *ngIf="element.weight < 10" style="height: 10px; width: 10px; border-radius: 10px; background: red"></div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhjzer?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: Thanks . I am was using  ` *ngIf="{{userRow.role}}!='r'" `  like this thus resulting in number of errors . And now it works . Thanks.